# How do I traverse one level up and search the html label and get the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I search one level up from the table td cell and find the label text.

**Html Code:**

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr id="cmpnyDetailRow" class="ui-widget-content ui-panelgrid-even" role="row">
    <td id="cmpnyLblCol" role="gridcell" style="text-align:right;">
        <label id="cmpnyLbl" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget outputmandatory">Company Name:</label>
    </td>
    <td id="cmpnyNameCol" role="gridcell">
        <input id="companyName" name="companyName" class="outputLabel" onchange="this.value = this.value.trim()" type="text">
    </td>
    <td id="cmpnyCityCol" role="gridcell" style="text-align:right;">
     <label id="cmpnyCityLbl" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget outputmandatory">City/Town:</label>
    </td>
    <td id="cmpnyCity" role="gridcell">
        <input id="city" name="city" class="outputLabel" onchange="this.value = this.value.trim()" type="text">
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Solution tried:**

```
$('#city').prev('td').find("label").text();
```

I unable to find, what is wrong in the code?

**Another Situation:**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="loginForm:j_username" style="text-align: right;font-size: 17px;" class="value-bold_new">User ID</label>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="loginForm:j_username" name="loginForm:j_username" value="uthrakumar@gxs.com" style="width:257px;height:36px;font-size: 15px;" tabindex="1" onchange="this.value = this.value.trim()" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Does this code work?**

```
$(document.getElementById('loginForm:j_username')).parent().prev('td').parent().prev('tr').find('label').text();
```

Nevertheless, I solved it.

```
$(document.getElementById('loginForm:j_username')).parent().parent().prev('tr').find('label').text();
```

Comment: Tried `$('#city').parent().prev('td').find("label").text();`?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#city').parent().prev('td').find("label").text();
```

add parent() function after city.

How it will work:

You have select the city element than you need to select he td by using the parent function and than it will reach to previous or next td.

Look at this link: [parant function in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: @y_r_k My pleasure I have edited the answer. please check that also.

Comment: @y_r_k You can this: `document.getElementById('city').parentNode.previousElementSibling.textContent` or for more appropriate `document.getElementById('city').parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector('label').textContent` use this one. it is same of your jquery

Answer (score 1):

You need to first select parent element of input [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2101/)

```
$('#city').parent().prev().find('label').text()
```